# how to write about 'double payment'

Tags: phrase-request

When the sum paid to someone increases twofold, what do you say to mean double payment?

> the sum paid as a double amount to someone.
>
> the payment doubles for someone.

Please suggest an idiomatic phrase!

Comment: Because *double* can be used as a verb, I think saying "The amount has doubled" is idiomatic. You may need to adjust the tense and add supporting phrases as you see fit in your context.

Comment: You can also use *double* transitively: *We have doubled your salary.*

Comment: Be careful about the phrase 'double payment' as that has a quite different meaning - paying twice for the same thing. Context is important when deciding but consider "the price doubled", "the cost increased by 100%" or, even, "x paid double the usual rate"

Comment: Right we need more context. Did the sum paid increase twofold because the price changed? Or was the payment made twice in error? Or what?

Comment: There's a good chance this Q of yours will get closed. I'm voting to leave open as I understood what you mean, but most others don't. Leaving an example could really help.

Comment: Close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what Damkerng says. The word *double* can be used as a verb.

> [doubled (v)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/double_5) - *to become, or make something become, twice as much or as many*

So, depending upon the context, you may use the verb *'double'*

> *You are paid double; The amount paid to you is double/d,* and so on...

PerryW's comment is also worth noting. Take care of that while using the word.